# mysql_fetch_rows shows invalid mysql resource

Tags: php, mysql

i am fetching data from a table 
using

```
mysql_fetch_aaray
```

the data is displaying correctly 
now i want that if data is not exist 
it will print no data found

i tried with the following code

```
ghgf
```

am getting error in mysql_num_rows
it shows

```
Warning: mysql_num_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resourc
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Warning: mysql_fetch_* expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11674312/warning-mysql-fetch-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given-error)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your question I found that in `if` condition you have not passed resource name properly

```
mysql_num_rows($result33) instead of `mysql_num_rows($result)`
```

This will seems to solve your warning(error)

Comment: there is a chance that your query is not proper,echo your query and fire it in phpmyadmin,just check it works or not

Answer (score 1):

Your SQL statement is probably throwing an error which you don't catch.

There might be something wrong with the SQL statement, or the tables don't have the same amout of fields - but those are just two shots in the dark.

To debug this further, try

```
$sql33="your sql here";
$result33=mysql_query($sql33);

if (!$result) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

Another one, you're referencing a wrong resource in your `if`-condition:

Change

```
if (mysql_num_r($result<=0))
```

to

```
if (mysql_num_rows($result33<=0))
```

Comment: Still a few problems with `if (mysql_num_r($result33<=0))`, such as missing "ows" in the function name and passing the Boolean expression `$result33 <= 0` to that function.

Comment: `mysql_num_r` is not known to me. Change `mysql_num_r` to `mysql_num_rows`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
    list($count) = mysql_fetch_row($result33);
if ($count<=0)
{
echo "No Data Found";

}
```

instead of:

```
    if (mysql_num_r($result<=0))
{
echo "No Data Found";

}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Function with name `mysql_num_r` does num exists. Use `mysql_num_rows` instead. But this is may be a typo.
2. You are passing result of boolean expression `$result<=0` to `mysql_num_rows`, not a resource. Place brackets correctly:

   `if( mysql_num_rows($result)<=0 )`